# Why does my JavaScript function accept three arrays, but not an array containing three arrays?

Tags: javascript, product, cartesian

```
function product() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(as, bs) {
        return [a.concat(b) for each (a in as) for each (b in bs)]
    }, [[]]);
}


arr4=[['4','4A','4B'],['16D','15D'],['5d','5e']];
alert(product(['4','4A','4B'],['16D','15D'],['5d','5e']);
```

The above works but the following don't work:

```
arr4=[['4','4A','4B'],['16D','15D'],['5d','5e']];
alert(product(arr4);
```

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: What kind of syntax is `[a.concat(b) for each (a in as) for each (b in bs)]`?  You sure you're using JavaScript, and not Python?

Comment: @Rocket: `for each (.. in ..)` is a Mozilla-supported extension to JavaScript which is not currently part of the ECMAScript standard (only part of an offshoot of the standard) and therefore may not be supported in non-Mozilla browsers such as Chrome or Internet Explorer or Safari. I would caution against using it. It's **actually** very good style, but one should be using `[].map` and `[].forEach` and `[].filter` and `[].reduce` etc. instead, which *are* standards-compliant and widely supported. (If you aren't happy using those, use jQuery's slightly-broken `$.each` or `$.map`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have either one or the other; otherwise it's poorly defined. (Unless you want to make the very questionable decision to do special-casing like "if my first argument is an array and each element is an array, return something different". Then you'll be remaking PHP in no time. =])

---

Use the [*somefunction*.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method instead; that's what it was made for. For example:

```
product.apply(this, arr4)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
product(arr4[0], arr4[1], ...)
```

If you do this a lot, you can define `product2(arrays) {return product.apply(this,arrays)}`.

---

However unless you want to do **both** `product([..], [..], ..)` and `product([[..],[..],..])`, this seems inelegant.

If you want this function to behave by default like `product([[..],[..],..])`, then the correct way to solve this is to modify the function to suit your needs. It is currently using the default "variadic" (multiple arguments) `arguments` variable special to javascript, which stands for an array representing all the arguments you passed into the function. This is not what you want, if you want normal-style fixed-number-of-arguments functions. First add in the appropriate parameter:

```
function product(arrays) {
    ...
}
```

and rather than using the default `arguments` variable, replace that with `arrays`.